# How to batch rename clip using sequential number

Tags: davinci-resolve

I have 300 clips on my timeline and I want to batch rename them using sequential number, for example to something like 'clip_xxx' format where xxx starts from 10 and increment is 10 :

```
clip_010
clip_020
clip_030
etc
```

Is it possible to do it in Resolve ?